# Kotlin:How to wait for function one from object to start another one from fragment?

Tags: android

I would like for my fragment to first end launch job and then do rest of the code, but it does not and i don't understand why.

```
                runBlocking {
val job = launch {
    Stopers.ITEMS.clear()

    val database =
        Firebase.database("myurl")
    val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
    Log.e(TAG, "User: ${user?.uid.toString()}")
    val myRef = database.getReference("${user?.uid.toString()}")
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            Stopers.ITEMS.clear()
            Stopers.COUNT = dataSnapshot.child("Number_of_stopers").getValue<Long>()!!.toLong()
            for (i in 1..Stopers.COUNT) {
                    .getValue<String>().toString()
                Stopers.addStoper()
        }

    })

}
                    job.join()
                        adapter = MyStoperRecyclerViewAdapter(Stopers.ITEMS, eventListListener)
                        Log.d(TAG,"Adapter: done")

                }
```

Comment: Please share code of this part, your description hard to give answer.

Comment: I edited, whole question in hope it is more understandable

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is your calling job inside the runBlocking itself, try this way.

```
val job = launch { 
 {
 //your first code
 }
}

runBlocking {
job.join()
//do what you wanted to do after
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work, i think it has something to do with geting data from firebase override
 fun onDataChange is working on second thread  and is not waitng for first event to go and start doing next stuff

Comment: I just found out that i can just set adaptert inside onDataChange